# Google Spreadsheet to android

Tags: android, google-sheets

I am having a spreadsheet in gmail. And now i need to get the details from spreadsheet and show it in android.If there is any way to achieve that programmatically. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through below link. It's self explanatory
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/